# How do I see the reason for an exception when stopped in objc_exception_throw?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode/GDB: How to get information about an exception that was just thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327828/xcode-gdb-how-to-get-information-about-an-exception-that-was-just-thrown)

My iPhone app is causing an exception to be thrown.  I have added an Exception Breakpoint, in Xcode, which causes the debugger to stop in `objc_exception_throw`.  How do I see the reason for the exception (the `NSException`'s `reason`)?  I can continue from the breakpoint, which causes the app to unwind the stack all the way to main() and log the exception in the output window, but then I lose the context that the exception occurred in.

Comment: The linked post ([Xcode/GDB: How to get information about an exception that was just thrown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327828/)) has information about how to print the exception in gdb but not in lldb.  I still haven't figured out how to do it in lldb.