# Debugging in XCode: Exception Breakpoints

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm debugging a random SIGTRAP crash right now that just happens in the background. It's probably something that has to do with an `NSManagedObjectContext` somewhere.

Besides that, I'm trying to debug it using an exception breakpoint to at least find out where it's originating from. The only problem is that the crash/breakpoint occurs in a 0 objc_exception_throw, which is no help to me.

The data I get back looks like this:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:
0x32a3a960:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr} // breakpoint stops here
0x32a3a962:  add    r7, sp, #12
0x32a3a964:  mov    r4, r0
0x32a3a966:  movs   r0, #16
0x32a3a968:  blx    0x32a46854                ; symbol stub for: -[NSObject isEqual:]
```

So my question is, how I can I create an exception breakpoint to initiate itself earlier? I'm trying to make the breakpoint occur in the last bit of actual Objective-C code before the crash.

I have tried editing the breakpoint to be shared, break on throw, then break on catch, and have changed the type of exception between Objective-C, C++, and "all" with no luck.

How can I make the exception breakpoint throw earlier?

Unless there is a way to decipher the code I posted. If that's possible, please give me a brief explanation of what it means, and how you deciphered it so I can learn to do so as well :)

Thanks everyone!

**If I let the program run...**

It continues to the crash, which looks like this:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
0x30830ea0:  mov    r12, sp
0x30830ea4:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r8}
0x30830ea8:  ldm    r12, {r4, r5, r6}
0x30830eac:  mvn    r12, #30
0x30830eb0:  svc    #128
0x30830eb4:  pop    {r4, r5, r6, r8} // SIGTRAP throws here
0x30830eb8:  bx     lr
```

**Stack trace when running command "bt" as a debugger command**

```
* thread #13: tid = 0x2337, 0x32a3a960 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x32a3a960 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x340f9fee CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 298
    frame #2: 0x341522d2 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 730
    frame #3: 0x32054b02 UIKit`__84-[UIManagedDocument writeContents:toURL:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:]_block_invoke_0 + 30
    frame #4: 0x34155bc0 CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 88
    frame #5: 0x36e3d4b6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 22
    frame #6: 0x36e419f6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 30
    frame #7: 0x34155d42 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 174
    frame #8: 0x32054862 UIKit`-[UIManagedDocument writeContents:toURL:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] + 986
    frame #9: 0x3205418a UIKit`-[UIManagedDocument writeContents:andAttributes:safelyToURL:forSaveOperation:error:] + 698
    frame #10: 0x32017ce4 UIKit`__block_global_4 + 68
    frame #11: 0x32017c80 UIKit`__block_global_3 + 156
    frame #12: 0x339c767c Foundation`-[NSFileCoordinator _invokeAccessor:thenCompletionHandler:] + 144
    frame #13: 0x339c791e Foundation`__73-[NSFileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]_block_invoke_0 + 90
    frame #14: 0x339c894e Foundation`-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _invokeAccessor:orDont:thenRelinquishAccessClaimForID:] + 202
    frame #15: 0x339c926c Foundation`-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateWritingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:] + 548
    frame #16: 0x339c78be Foundation`-[NSFileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:] + 90
    frame #17: 0x32017254 UIKit`-[UIDocument _coordinateWritingItemAtURL:error:byAccessor:] + 720
    frame #18: 0x320179a0 UIKit`__59-[UIDocument saveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_0 + 284
    frame #19: 0x36e3e11e libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
    frame #20: 0x36e41ece libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 142
    frame #21: 0x36e41dc0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 40
    frame #22: 0x36e4291c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 184
    frame #23: 0x36e42ac0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 84
    frame #24: 0x33ba7a10 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 360
    frame #25: 0x33ba78a4 libsystem_c.dylib`start_wqthread + 8
```

**Check out the link that Matt Wilding posted in the comments of his answer!**

Comment: The debug navigator in Xcode doesn't help? Even at the highest 'resolution'?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's the most bizarre crash I've ever seen.

Comment: Weird. Sometimes one can hit the 'play' button in the debugger and the frameworks writes a more useful error message. But I assume, that you tried that and the debugger just sticks to the crash line...?

Comment: I added some code to show where it crashes.

Comment: @jsksma2 were to able to resolve what was causing this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have much control over where that breakpoint triggers. Once you've hit the breakpoint though, you can use the `bt` command to print the current stack trace.

---

EDIT: With the backtrace...

It looks like UIDocument's `-saveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:` method is the culprit. I've never used the class before, so I can't help too much. If you're calling that method anywhere in your code (like from a block?), you could also put a breakpoint there, in anticipation of the failure.

Comment: Is that command what I would enter in for a "debugger command"?

Comment: You could certainly do that if you don't want to type it by hand.

Comment: I add the stack trace in my question.

Comment: Ummm here's the thing; I'm not using that anywhere within my code. However, I'm afraid that that method is called automatically when working with Core Data. I know you said that you're unfamiliar with that method, but do you have any ideas? Also, how did you figure out that that was the culprit? Thanks!

Comment: It was an educated guess based on the trace. It's at the bottom of the callstack that results in `[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` throwing an exception. Since it's public API, it's something that you could be calling yourself.

Comment: As for next steps, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327828/xcode-gdb-how-to-get-information-about-an-exception-that-was-just-thrown) for info on the exception itself.

Comment: That link is amazing! Thank you so much.