# Runs on Simulator but not on Device

Tags: ios, objective-c

Been having issues running on my device (both on XCode 5 and XCode6) and both iOS7 and iOS8.  I received the following error:

```
 *argv  char *  "/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9943DB7F-C186-49D6-913A-ED95EDC8CBA0/idcdoor.app/idcdoor"    =\]{
```

't80x00183bdc

The interesting thing is when I "step-over" or click the play button, it forwards on into the Application on the device with no issues.  Also, if I stop the Application, and re-open, it runs fine. Any help or insight on what I can try would be appreciated.

EDIT
Here is the stack:

```
 Queue: com.apple.main-thread(serial)
 0_cxa_throw
 UIApplicationMain
 Main
```

Here is where is where the exception is thrown:

```
 int main(int argc, char * argv[])
 {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([idcAppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

Comment: You probably have a global exceptions breakpoint. Turn it off.

Comment: That's not an error message.

Comment: @jeffamaphone - I added the stack trace.  thanks

Comment: @matt - I turned it off but didn't fix the issue when I install the App via TestFlight using the IPA

Comment: If only TestFlight causes the problem, don't use TestFlight.

Comment: So [what is the exception](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3327954/74815)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. It seems to be that my storyboard got messed up somehow. Try right clicking on your `.storyboard` and `open as -> Source Code`. I had a few lines near the top that looked like this:

```
<customFonts key="customFonts">     
    <mutableArray key="arial.ttf">      
        <string>ArialMT</string>        
        <string>ArialMT</string>        
        <string>ArialMT</string>        
        <string>ArialMT</string>        
        <string>ArialMT</string>        
        ...     
    </mutableArray>     
</customFonts>
```

I don't know why it is importing Arial as a custom font, let alone 35 times. I deleted that entire block and now it's not throwing the error. My problem could be unique, but it's not a terrible idea to open up your storyboard as text and looking for anything that seems odd.