# How to replace NSUncaughtExceptionHandler with definition in Breakpoint navigator?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, breakpoints, nsexception

So far I used `NSUncaughtExceptionHandler` within code:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"*************************************************");
    NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
    NSLog(@"*************************************************");
}

NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *exceptionHandlerPtr = &uncaughtExceptionHandler;
```

I know that in Xcode I can **Add Exception Breakpoint** for all exceptions:

[image]

Then I can **Edit Breakpoint**:

[image]

and finally I do not know how to configure this to replace my code from `NSUncaughtExceptionHandler`.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution from [WWDC 15 - Advanced Debugging and the Address Sanitizer](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=413).

[image]

Example output is:

[image]

You can also read [Xcode: One Weird Debugging Trick That Will Save Your Life](http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/)

Comment: I'd also add http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/ -> comment 1 from Sidney de Koning "And if you ctrl-click on the breakpoint and select 'Move breakpoint to => user', you have it in every project you create :-) Double the awesomeness!"