# Is Xcode debugging/crash report in Swift broken?

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging, xcode7

I've been working with Swift for over a year now and things seems to be only getting worse with each new Xcode release.

Is it only here that crashes in a app aren't reported correctly? Most of the time it's only `SIGBRT` or `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` on `main()` (yes I use a main.m in my project):

[image]

[image]

That's not helpful. If I don't add an 'All Exceptions' breakpoint, I can't find where the crash happened. I just got used with not having any help at all from LLVM about any errors on my Swift code, and even then:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing here? I feel like back when I was programming with Objective-C things were much better.

**UPDATE**

I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27356008/447360

Which helps sometimes:

[image]

Still looking on how to get the exception/error message to show up (again) in Xcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I finally was able to improve the debugging info for breakpoints.

Basically you should create a "All Exceptions" breakpoint like this:

[image]

This is for Xcode 7+ only.

Credit:

http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31471663/447360

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535007/447360

Answer (score 3):

Check if the "Debug -> Debug Workflow -> Always Show Disassembly" is turned off.

[image: The Debug dropdown menu, workflow section]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10377556)

Comment: Actually I uploaded an image, which ilustrates what I've said above, but due to my currently low rep I can only post it as a link.  :)

Comment: There is upload image option available in editor (Ctrl+G), do check out, I dont think its restrictive by rep. , please check the option once, It would be useful for you later.

Comment: Not what I was looking for. With this option turned on, Xcode now shows the Assembly code where the exception/error happened - but that doesn't help with finding the actual problem. I'm still getting "signal SIGABRT" without much explanation, only this time in the Assembly code.

Comment: As I said, check if the option is **turned off**. But that doesn't seem to be causing the issue you're having anyway.